# update openssl, do not work hmac

Tags: c++, openssl, hmac

there is code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

int main() {
    const char key[] = "012345678";
    char data[] = "hello world";
    unsigned char* result;
    unsigned int len = 20;
    result = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    HMAC_CTX ctx;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, strlen(key), EVP_sha1(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&ctx, (unsigned char*)&data, strlen(data));
    HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    printf("HMAC digest: ");

    for (int i = 0; i != len; i++)
        printf("%02x", (unsigned int)result[i]);

    printf("\n");
    free(result);

}
```

output HMAC digest: e19e220122b37b708bfb95aca2577905acabf0c0

I can not update this code for openssl 1.1.0.
The new version changed the syntax hmac.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>


using namespace std;
int main() {
    const char key[] = "012345678";
    char data[] = "hello world";
    int datalen = strlen(data);
    int keylen = strlen(key);


    unsigned char* result;
    unsigned int len = 20;
    result = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    cout << datalen  << endl;
    cout << keylen  << endl;
    cout << len  << endl;

    HMAC_CTX *HMAC_CTX_new();
    int HMAC_CTX_reset(HMAC_CTX *ctx);
    int HMAC_Init_ex(HMAC_CTX *ctx, const  char key, int keylen, const EVP_MD  EVP_sha1());
    int HMAC_Update(HMAC_CTX * ctx,  char &data, int datalen);
    int HMAC_Final(HMAC_CTX * ctx, char result, int &len);
    int HMAC_CTX_cleanup(HMAC_CTX * ctx);

    printf("HMAC digest: ");

    for (int i = 0; i != len; i++)
        printf("%02x", (unsigned int)result[i]);

    printf("\n");
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

output HMAC digest: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I will be glad of any help

Comment: Your second code block doesn't change `result`. You have just copied the prototypes of the functions. You have to **call** the functions if you expect result to change like in your first code block.

Comment: you can write an example?

Comment: They're mostly the same functions...have you even tried?  (SO is not a code writing service after all...)

Comment: Of course I tried. I have obtained all the time  HMAC digest: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: You seem confused about the difference between a function **prototype** and a function **call**. What happens if you use the first code block with the new library? In your second block, you just define the function prototypes, you don't actually _call_ any of the library functions. So the `result` array isn't changed from what `malloc` initializes it to. So it's no surprise at all that it's all zeroes.

Comment: the problem decided. thanks to all